# Using Reflection while iterating over a map

Tags: java, reflection, dictionary, iterator

I can't figure out how to use reflection to call this inner method, here's what I came up with. However, it doesn't work:

```
interface Foo {
   void callMe();
} 

 public class Tester{

 public TreeMap<Integer, Foo> testMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Foo>();

 public void foo(Foo foo, Integer d) {
    testMap.put(d, foo);
}

 public void testCase() { 
    for (Integer key: testMap.keySet()) {
       testMap.get(key).callMe(d);   
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

 Tester testUser = new tester();

 testUser.foo(new Foo(){ void callMe(Integer d){ 
   System.out.println("Test " + d); } 
  }, 5);

testUser.foo(new Foo(){ void callMe(Integer d){ 
   System.out.println("Test Two " + d); } 
  }, 10);

   testUser.testCase();

 }
}
```

What changes do I have to make to the code so that it will run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) This isn't reflection

b) You should be using `testUser.foo(...)` instead of `tester.foo(...)`

Comment: then what is it? Im trying to pass a interface to the TreeMap's value and execute the inner method of that interface

Comment: That's a callback object, approximately.  (Buzzwords are overrated in any event.)

Comment: ...The suggestion I made in part b) is the main one.  Everything else looks good.